# Злоупотребление рефакторингом Extract Method

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Как называется антипаттерн, если когда вместо простого вызов *а* -> *б*, пишут *а* -> *б_промежуточное (выделенный метод)*-> *б*.

Т.е. грубо говоря злоупотребили рефакторингом **Extract Method**, думая, что *б* может изменится, но *б* никогда не будет меняться.

Тем самым мы усложняем отладку и понимание кода другими людьми.

Comment: Каждый, как говорится, по своему с ума сходит. Плохо, что эту дурь порой спрашивают на собеседование, и если ты, вдруг, не вспомнил название этой дури, так как она совершенно бесполезна и перпендикулярна реальному программированию, то тебе дают от ворот поворот.:) И еще страшнее, когда такие дураки наверх пролазят и устраивают подобные собеседования.:)

Comment: да как угодно. я такой "антипаттерн" вживую не встечал. и сомневаюсь, что у него вообще общепринятое название есть.

Comment: в смысле? у меня сегодня возникла такая ситуация в реальном проекте. Конкретно - [здесь](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/buffer.js#L173) Нужно было вызывать просто `b instanceof Buffer`, а не `isBuffer`

Comment: @PashaPash Можно легко встретить усложнение кода, тем не менее нет никакой необходимости запоминать эти паттерны и тем более их названия.:)

Comment: @hellboy ну так дайте по рукам/напишите в пуллреквесте коммент "нафига?" и все дела. зачем для мелкого овердизайна придумывать название.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow это вопрос не про паттерны и не про техники рефакторинга (у них как раз есть устоявшиеся названия - надо ж как-то кнопки в IDE называть) - а про что-то совсем странное.

Comment: @PashaPash, нет, это про антипаттерны. Но что-то сомневаюсь, что название есть.

Comment: Проблема решается рефакторингом [Inline Method](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/inline-method)

Comment: У меня просто была такая болезнь проф роста, вот я и спрашиваю у врачей, как называется такой диагноз

Comment: Вот у Node.js тоже была такая же проблема роста: [`util.isBuffer`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L699) объявили [устаревшим](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_isbuffer_object), т.к. он тупо вызывает `Buffer.isBuffer`, который в свою очередь вызывает `instanceOf`

Comment: И где гарантия того, что `Buffer.isBuffer` в следующей версии не объявят устаревшим? Не проще ли везде использовать `ìnstaceOf`?

Comment: В англоязычной версии сайта тоже есть [вопрос по этому поводу](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21858138/444079)

Comment: @hellboy ну там же никто не пытается придумать для этого отдельное название.

Comment: @PashaPash название есть для всего. Вот внизу ответили. Интересно, что в сети только одно место, где это объясняется по-русски.

Comment: @hellboy это явный признак того, что это название/объяснение - не общепринятое. Или, по крайней мере, не распространенное. Т.е. нельзя ткнуть пальцем в метод и сказать "это Speculative Generality" или "Спекулятивная общность"/"Теоретическая общность" - потому что придется объяснять, что вы имели ввиду.

Comment: запах "Speculative Generality" описан в книге Фаулера, которую должен прочитать каждый программист.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Speculative generality](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/speculative-generality), видимо

Теоретическая общность возникает, когда говорят о том, что в будущем, наверное, потребуется возможность делать такие вещи, и хотят обеспечить набор механизмов для работы с вещами, которые не нужны.

Ситуация возникает, когда ведется широкомасштабная подготовка к реализации кучи возможностей, которые так и не воплощаются в жизнь.

То, что получается в результате, труднее понимать и сопровождать. Если бы все эти механизмы использовались, их наличие было бы оправданно, в противном случае они только мешают, поэтому избавляйтесь от них.

В результате приходится выметать эти излишние приготовления.

Метлами служат: если есть абстрактные классы, не приносящие большой пользы, избавляйтесь от них путем «Сворачивания иерархии» (`Collapse Hierarhy`).

Уничтожение иерархии при ненужном наследовании, ненужное делегирование можно устранить с помощью «Встраивания класса» (`Inline Class`).

Методы с неиспользуемыми параметрами должны быть подвергнуты «Удалению параметров» (`Remove Parameter`).

Методы со слишком общими и непонятными именами необходимо вернуть на землю путем «Переименования метода» (`Rename Method`).